# Sharepoint 2007 HTML Form submitting to PHP Script not working

Tags: php, html, forms, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am working in Sharepoint Designer 2007 through the web API to set up a form for a client of mine. The form simply collects some data, and upon submit, a PHP script compiles the data into a formatted email and sends to a designated address.

I am using a "Blank Web Part Page" (for plain HTML) and using the "Form Web Editor" part to place my form's code.

Currently what happens is after I fill out all the fields (properly), I click "submit", in which the action should take me to the PHP script (which has HTML within it for a confirmation page), but the page simply reloads (I assume - I just see the "loading" symbol on the browser tab) and then does nothing. And I get no email, so I know it's not reaching the script.

I have tested this using plain HTML pages, so I know that my code works (both the form code and the PHP script), so clearly there is something with Sharepoint/ASPX that is not allowing me to get the form to function properly.

I have tried to insert the PHP script into an actual page, but apparently neither the plain HTML editor nor the Form Editor Part will accept PHP code, because it just shows all my PHP code as plain text while the HTML for the confirmation page is intact. I have tried wrapping it in HTML tags to no avail.

Additionally, I have tried to simply upload the PHP script as it's own page (without embedding it, just uploading it to site content under Pages) - this didn't work. I tried the same thing again, but under Documents instead of Pages.

Here is my HTML Form Code:

```
    <FORM id="RegForm2013" name="htmlform" action="/members/member-homepage/Documents/html_form_send.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain" >

    <div align="center">

<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody><tr>
    <td align="right" class="style4">Coordinating Allergist</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="allergist" id="allergist" size="30"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="132" align="right" class="style4">Address</td>
    <td width="248"><input name="address" id="address" size="30" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right" class="style4">City</td>
    <td><input name="city" id="city" size="30" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right" class="style4">State</td>
    <td><input name="state" id="state" size="30" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right" class="style4">Zip</td>
    <td><input name="zip" id="zip" size="30" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right" class="style4">Office phone</td>
    <td><input name="phone" id="office_phone" size="30" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right" class="style4">Office fax</td>
    <td><input name="fax" id="office_fax" size="30" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right" class="style4">E-Mail</td>
    <td><input name="email" id="Email" size="30" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center">
<input name="subject" id="form_id" value="RegForm2013" type="hidden">
<input name="submit" id="button" value="Submit" type="submit">
</td>
</tr>


</tbody></table>


    </div>
  </form>
```

I pasted my code just for reference, but I'm fairly certain the issue is with Sharepoint and not the code, does anyone have any insight on how to get custom forms to function properly in Sharepoint Designer 2007, as well does anyone have guidance on how to handle getting my PHP script to be recognized by the form when submit is clicked? Any overview of how Sharepoint forms works will help! Even if it is to say that it's not possible...

If anyone should need to see the PHP script, let me know

Thank you everyone :)

Comment: You can commiserate with other Sharepoint users over here, where you are more likely to find an answer: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of the Form Web Editor part you use the Content Editor Web Part.  This web part allows you to host virtually any kind of HTML inside sharepoint.  To use it you would simply copy+paste your code into the web part.  You may have to work with the layout afterward, however.

Here's some info on it:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/content-editor-web-part-HA010024046.aspx

Also you can use the Page Viewer Web Part to point to an HTML page (or really any web page) and have it appear to be hosted in SharePoint even if it isn't.  It works by encasing the url in an IFrame.

And here's some info on it:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/page-viewer-web-part-HA010024045.aspx